# how to execute ruby script from rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to ruby on rails and trying to build an internal site to manage
several ruby scripts. What I am trying to accomplish; create web page
where an user clicks on a link (Execute Analyzer) to execute ruby script
(runs in the background - FitAnalyzer.rb). I am having trouble
understanding how to route this without redirecting to another web page.
I basically need help how to add the correct format to routes.rb.

**analyzer.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "![Execute][1] Analyzer", :controller =>
'fit_anlayzer_controller', :method => 'execute_analyzer'%>
```

**fit_analyzer_controller.rb**

```
class FitAnalyzerController < ApplicationController
  def analyzer
  end

  def execute_analyzer
    # Delayed::Job.enqueue(AnalyzerJob.new(params[:id]), 3)
    # command = 'ruby ~/ruby_scripts/fit_analyzer/FitAnalyzer.rb'
    @execute_command = system 'ruby
/Users/gsypolt/rubyqa_project/ruby_scripts/fit_analyzer/FitAnalyzer.rb'
    flash[:notice] = "Executing FitNesse Analyzer"
  end
end
```

When accessing mylocalhost/fit_analyzer/analyzer receiving
this message below

```
No route matches {:controller=>"fit_anlayzer_controller",
:method=>"execute_analyzer", :popup=>true}
```

I have been learning ruby on rails from lyndia.com and book (rails 3
way)

mockup screenshot what i am trying to build

Comment: If you want to send a request without leaving the page, use Ajax.

Comment: Method in this case corresponds to the http method (get, put, delete, post).  You'll either need to use a URL helper method or specify a controller and action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add a route

```
# config/routes.rb
match "fit_analyzer/analyzer" => 'fit_analyzer#execute_analyzer'
```

The `fit_analyzer#execute_analyzer` corresponds to `controller#action`

Then you need to call it using ajax. To do that add a `:remote => true` to your `link_to`

Comment: thanks for everyone responding all the information has been helpful understanding how to send remote request by staying on the same page. i have made a few tweaks and now encountering the following issue now "uninitialized constant FitAnalyzerControllerController"

Comment: **uninitialized constant FitAnalyzerControllerController** i have been searching how to initialize controller, no luck at this time. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to your code the name should be FitAnalyzerController (notice "Controller" is written just once)

Comment: gotcha now got to understand why it is adding additional "Controller" to the controller class FitAnalyzerController. For Rails best practices are you suppose to generate controller name without controller in the naming convention? I will double check my code...